# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

Tags: android

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if (camera == null) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        camera.startPreview();
        camera.setErrorCallback(new ErrorCallback() {
            public void onError(int error, Camera mcamera) {

                camera.release();
                camera = Camera.open();
                Log.d("Camera died", "error camera");

            }
        });
    }
    if (camera != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
            setCameraDisplayOrientation(context,
                    CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, camera);
        preview.setCamera(camera);
    }
}


Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
            at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:545)
            at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:403)
            at info.androidhive.tendigimrapp.activity.CameraDemo.onResume(CameraDemo.java:93)
```

when i launch first time this Actvity  then this Exception not coming when i come back previous actvity and we go cameraDemo Actvity then this Exception coming please tell me how to fix this Error i have tried but not able to fix
excepiton coming at     camera = Camera.open();

Comment: Call camera.release (); in onStop method of Camera activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
public void onStop() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
    }
}
```